# NSNotification multithreading is not working after migration to Xcode 4.3 and IOS 5

Tags: ios, multithreading, notifications

I have migrated my working application from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4.2 IOS 5 and the code for notifications does not fire. I have used NSNotificationsAdditions to ensure I send all the notifications on to the main thread everytime. Yes, what works in earlier version does not work now.

```
- (void) postNotificationOnMainThread:(NSNotification *) notification {
     if( [NSThread isMainThread] ) return [self postNotification:notification];
     [self postNotificationOnMainThread:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) postNotificationOnMainThread:(NSNotification *) notification waitUntilDone:(BOOL) wait {
    if( [NSThread isMainThread] ) return [self postNotification:notification];
    [[self class] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( _postNotification: ) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:wait];
}

+ (void) _postNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [[self defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
}

- (void) postNotificationOnMainThreadWithName:(NSString *) name object:(id) object {
    if([NSThread isMainThread] ) return [self postNotificationName:name object:object userInfo:nil];
    [self postNotificationOnMainThreadWithName:name object:object userInfo:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) postNotificationOnMainThreadWithName:(NSString *) name object:(id) object userInfo:(NSDictionary *) userInfo {
     if([NSThread isMainThread]) return [self postNotificationName:name object:object userInfo:userInfo];
     [self postNotificationOnMainThreadWithName:name object:object userInfo:userInfo waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) postNotificationOnMainThreadWithName:(NSString *) name object:(id) object userInfo:(NSDictionary *) userInfo waitUntilDone:(BOOL) wait {
    if([NSThread isMainThread]) return [self postNotificationName:name object:object userInfo:userInfo];
    NSMutableDictionary *info = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    if( name ) [info setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    if( object ) [info setObject:object forKey:@"object"];
    if( userInfo ) [info setObject:userInfo forKey:@"userInfo"];
    [[self class] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( _postNotificationName: ) withObject:info waitUntilDone:wait];
    [info release];
}

+ (void) _postNotificationName:(NSDictionary *) info {
    NSString *name = [info objectForKey:@"name"];
    id object = [info objectForKey:@"object"];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [info objectForKey:@"userInfo"];
    [[self defaultCenter] postNotificationName:name object:object userInfo:userInfo];
}
```